# POST Request in Playframework Java

Tags: java, playframework

Hi In my playframework application I want to do a simple Post request.

So I defined in my Route this:

```
POST        /printName                              @controllers.Index.printName()
```

Same way I do it in scala.

Then I have the following controller function:

```
public Result printName(Http.Request request) {
    JsonNode json = request.body().asJson();
    return ok("Got name: " + json.get("name").asText());
}
```

So now compiler returns:

> missing arguments for method printName in class Index;
>   follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function

When I add the parameter in The route like this:

```
POST        /printName                  @controllers.Index.printName(request: Request)
```

Then I got this error

> not found: type Request

How would it be correct? Example is from Playframework page: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaBodyParsers#The-default-body-parser

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

controller function

```
public Result printName() {
    Http.Request request = request();
    JsonNode json = request.body().asJson();
    return ok("Got name: " + json.get("name").asText());
}
```

and the route

```
POST        /printName              @controllers.Index.printName()
```